# RUN FAILED exit value -1 073 741 819 - what's wrong with my code?

Tags: c, gcc, netbeans, mingw

I'm trying to make a stopwatch program, which will write `czas` to `file.txt`. I started learning C today, so please be lenient for me, if it's a stupid question, but the compiler doesn't throw out any errors, and NetBeans also doesn't display any exclamation marks. There is my code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#define sleep(x) Sleep(1000 * x)

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int a = 0;
int czas = 0;
int main (void)
{
    FILE *file;
    while (a < 30) { /*repeats only 30 times*/
        a = a + 1; /*increases the counter for while loop*/
        file = fopen("file.txt","w"); /*opens file.txt for writing*/
        fprintf(file,"%s", czas); /*writes czas to file.txt*/
        fclose(file); /*closes file.txt to save*/ 
        czas = czas + 1; /*increases czas for writing to file*/
    }
 return 0;
}
```

Could somebody help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%s` needs a `char*` as referring parameter.

You want to write out an `int`, which expects `%d`.

For details on this please see `man fprintf`.

---

In case you like to have every new value of `czas` on a new line you can specify this in the `fprintf()` statement like so:

```
fprintf(file,"%d\n", czas);
```

Comment: Oh, now I see, thank you very much. Could you tell me where can I find `man printf` under Windows?

Comment: 'In case ou ylike to have every new value of czas on a new line you ight like to specify this in the fprintf() statement liek so:
fprintf(file,"%d\n", czas);' Thanks, but then I should'nt close the file, cause it'll wipe each time, am I right?

Comment: In the case of your example: Yes. In general opening a file does not necessarily truncates the file to zero lenght, destroys its content. Read regarding the possible value for `fopen()`'s second parameter `mode`.